# Performance Issue with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is DataSet at my Notebook’s Virtual Machine:

2 million unique Customers [:VISITED] 40000 unique Merchants. 
Every [:VISIT] has properties: amount (double) and dt (date). 
Every Customer has property “pty_id” (Integer). 
And every Merchant has mcht_id (String) property.

One Customer may visit one Merchant for more than one time. And of course, one Customer may visit many Merchants. So there are 43 978 539 relationships in my graph between Customers and Merchants.

I have created Indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX on :Customer(pty_id)
CREATE INDEX  on :Merchant(mcht_id)
```

Parameters of my VM are:

*Oracle (RedHat) Linux 7 with 2 core i7, 2 GB RAM*

Parameters of my Neo4j 3.5.7 config:

```
- dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1024m
- dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512m
```

My task is:

Get top 10 Customers ordered by total_amount who spent their money at NOT specified Merchant(M) but visit that Merchants which have been visited by Customers who visit this specified Merchant(M)

My Solution is:

```
Let’s M will have mcht_id = "0000000DA5"
```

Then the CYPHER query will be:

```
MATCH 
  (c:Customer)-[r:VISITED]->(mm:Merchant)<-[:VISITED]-(cc:Customer)-[:VISITED]->(m:Merchant {mcht_id: "0000000DA5"}) 
WHERE 
  NOT (c)-[:VISITED]->(m) 
WITH 
  DISTINCT c as uc 
MATCH 
  (uc:Customer)-[rr:VISITED]->()
RETURN 
  uc.pty_id
  ,round(100*sum(rr.amount))/100 as v_amt 
ORDER BY v_amt DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Result is OK. I receive my answer:

> uc.pty_id - v_amt: 1433798    - 348925.94; 739510 - 339169.83; 374933 -
>   327962.95 and so on.

The problem is that this result I have received after 437613 ms! It’s about 7 minutes!!! My estimated time for this query was about 10-20 seconds….

My Question is: What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Can you share the result of `PROFILE` of this query?

Comment: @Raj http://fs001.homme.io/111/plan.png

Comment: @Raj Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 1021125588 total db hits in 1624172 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to improve here.

First, for graph-wide queries in a graph with millions of nodes and 50 million relationships, 1G of heap and 512M of pagecache is far too low. We usually recommend around 8-10G of heap minimum for medium to large graphs (this is your "scratch space" memory as a query executes), and to try to get as much of the graph size as possible in pagecache if you can to minimize cache misses as you traverse the graph. Neo4j likes memory. Memory is relatively cheap. You can use [neo4j-admin memrec](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-memrec/) to get a recommendation of how to configure your memory settings, but in general you need to run this on a machine with more memory.

And if we're talking about hardware recommendations, usage of SSDs is highly recommended, for when you do need to hit the disk.

As for the query itself, notice in the query plan you posted that your DISTINCT operation drops the number of rows from the neighborhood of 26-35 million to only 153k rows, that's significant. Your most expensive step here (`WHERE 
  NOT (c)-[:VISITED]->(m)`) is the `Expand(Into)` operation on the right side of the plan, with nearly 1 billion db hits. This is happening too early in the query - you should be doing this AFTER your DISTINCT operation, so it operates on only 153k rows instead of 35 million.

You can also improve upon this so you don't even have to hit the graph to do that step of the filtering. Instead of using that `WHERE NOT <pattern>` approach, you can pre-match to the customers who visited the first merchant, gather them into a list, and keep them around, and instead of using negation of the pattern (where it has to actually expand out all :VISITED relationships of those customers and see if any was the original merchant), we instead do a list membership check, and ensure they aren't one of the 1k or so customers who visited the original merchant. That will happen in memory, since we already collected that list, so it shouldn't hit the graph. In any case you should do DISTINCT before this check.

In your RETURN you're performing an aggregation with respect to a node's unique property, so you're paying the cost of projecting that property across 4 million rows BEFORE the cardinality drops from the aggregation to 153k rows, meaning you're projecting out that property redundantly across a great many duplicate :Customer nodes before they become distinct from the aggregation. That's redundant and expensive property access you can avoid by aggregating with respect to the node instead, and then do your property access after the aggregation, and also after your sort and limit, so you only have to project out 10 properties.

So putting that all together, try this out:

```
MATCH 
  (cc:Customer)-[:VISITED]->(m:Merchant {mcht_id: "0000000DA5"}) 
WITH m, collect(DISTINCT cc) as visitors
UNWIND visitors as cc
MATCH (uc:Customer)-[:VISITED]->(mm:Merchant)<-[:VISITED]-(cc)
WHERE 
  mm <> m
WITH 
  DISTINCT visitors, uc 
WHERE NOT uc IN visitors
MATCH 
  (uc:Customer)-[rr:VISITED]->()
WITH 
  uc, round(100*sum(rr.amount))/100 as v_amt 
ORDER BY v_amt DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN uc.pty_id, v_amt;
```

EDIT

Okay, let's try something else. I suspect that what we're encountering here is a great deal of duplicates during expansion (many visitors may have visited the same merchants). Cypher won't eliminate duplicates during traversal unless you explicitly ask for it (as it may need this info for doing aggregations such as counting of occurrences), and this query is highly dependent on getting distinct nodes during expansion.

If you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), we can make use of some expansion procs which let us change how Cypher expands, only visiting each distinct node once across all paths. That may improve the timing here. At the least it will show us if the slowdown we're seeing is related to deduplication of nodes during expansion, or if it's something else.

```
MATCH (m:Merchant {mcht_id: "0000000DA5"}) 
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(m, {uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL', relationshipFilter:'VISITED', minLevel:3, maxLevel:3}) YIELD path
WITH last(nodes(path)) as uc
MATCH 
  (uc:Customer)-[rr:VISITED]->()
WITH 
  uc
  ,round(100*sum(rr.amount))/100 as v_amt 
ORDER BY v_amt DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN uc.pty_id, v_amt;
```

While this is a more complicated approach, one neat thing is that with NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness (ensuring we only visit each node once across all expanded paths) and bfs expansion, we don't need to include `WHERE NOT (c)-[:VISITED]->(m)` since this will naturally be ruled out; we would have already visited every visitor of `m`, and since they've already been visited, we cannot visit them again, so none of them will appear in the final result set at 3 hops.

Give this a try and run it a couple times to get that into pagecache (or as much as possible...with 512MB pagecache you may not be able to get all of the traversed structure into memory).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail and professional answer!

I have run your query and it takes ~200 sec at 2GB-2CPU environment and ~130 sec at 8GB-4CPU env. 

However, even 2 minutes is too slow. I have run analog SQL query to Oracle 12C XE that contains my DataSet and it takes ~12 sec at 2GB-2CPU without any deep optimization – only indexes and statistic. 

So I have been confused these results because just before tests I have read this post https://neo4j.com/news/how-much-faster-is-a-graph-database-really/ and  my expectations about Neo4j performance were different.

Comment: Can you attach the PROFILE plan of this query? Let's take a look at what's going on.

Comment: I have cleared my test stand: kill any unnecessary processes, check free memory and so on. So at i7 2,3 GHz, SSD, 4 cores, 8 GB RAM, heap.max_size=4g and pagecache.size=3584m results are:

1) your first query (...UNWIND visitors as cc...): 102827 ms first run; ~13704 ms second and subsequent runs

2) your second query (...apoc.path.expandConfig..): 98143 ms first run; ~5456 ms second and subsequent runs.

Thank you very much for your help! It's excellent result! Of course I am very eager to optimise my Oracle query :)

Comment: PROFILEs are: http://fs001.homme.io/111/plan2.png and http://fs001.homme.io/111/plan3.png

Comment: Nice, those results look much better! Once most of the graph you touched is in the pagecache those timings drop quite nicely. As for the profiles, those were run with EXPLAIN, which doesn't give us actual db hits or row information. Could you use PROFILE instead?

Comment: PROFILE for "....apoc.path.expandConfig..." query fs001.homme.io/111/plan3_2.png. Is it necessary to create PROFILE for query "...UNWIND visitors as cc...."?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested all optimised query on Neo4j and on Oracle. Results are:

Oracle - 2.197 sec 
Neo4j  - 5.326 sec

You can see details here: http://homme.io/41163#run

And there is more complimentared for Neo4j case at http://homme.io/41721.